# Telerik RadGrid Inline Editing Modifying the look and feel of it

Tags: asp.net, css, radgrid, edit, telerik-grid

I would like to change the styling on my RadGrid inline Edit template look. How do I achieve this without needing to add a huge amount of CSS  to my code backend?

Comment: Which style, the style for each controls, or for the edit region?

Comment: Yes, I would like to style each control and the regions as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of properties exposed by the grid for you to manipulate:

```
<telerik:RadGrid 
        ID="radgrid"
        runat="server"
        Skin="Vista">
        <MasterTableView 
            ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
            AlternatingItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
            EditFormSettings-FormMainTableStyle-BorderColor="#555555"
            EditFormSettings-FormMainTableStyle-Width="100%"
            EditFormSettings-FormMainTableStyle-BorderWidth="2px"
            EditFormSettings-FormMainTableStyle-BackColor="#f5f5f5"
            CommandItemDisplay="Top">
            <Columns>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

If you look through the available properties you'll see there are many more.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain why I am unable to post a comment but yes, I would like to style the containing TDs and the controls. Also, I would also like to somehow make sure hidden template controls stay hidden when the form is in edit mode.